# stripe payment returning invalid integer erroer message

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I hope someone sees this fast and help out

I am using stripe checkout and stripe php package in my laravel project, at first it worked when i tested it but when i added the stripe charges to the amount it was now giving me the invalid interger error

here is my controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Saving;
use App\Transaction;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Stripe\Charge;
use Stripe\Customer;
use Stripe\Stripe;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{


    public function charge(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $amount = $data['amount'];
        $final_amount = $amount;
        $charge = ($final_amount / 100) * 2.9;
        $final_charge = $final_amount + $charge + 0.30;
        $wallet_balance = Auth::user()->wallet->balance;
        $user = Auth::user()->wallet;

        $new_balance =  $final_amount +  $wallet_balance;

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'));

            $customer = Customer::create(array(
                'email' => $request->stripeEmail,
                'source' => $request->stripeToken
            ));

            $charge = Charge::create(array(
                'customer' => $customer->id,
                'amount' => $final_charge,
                'currency' => 'usd'
            ));

            $saving = Saving::create([
                'amount' => $final_amount,
                'user_id' => Auth::id()
            ]);

            $transaction = Transaction::create([
                'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                'Description' => '' . Auth::user()->username . ' saved ' . $final_amount . ' via Stripe',
                'amount' => $final_amount,
                'payment_type' => 'savings',
                'reference' => Str::random(10),
                'status' => 'completed'
            ]);

            $user->update([
                'balance' => $new_balance
            ]);

            DB::commit();
            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Savings Recieved!');
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            DB::rollback();
            return redirect()->back()->with('warning', '' . $ex->getMessage() . '');
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that the amount filed in the saving and transaction model is a double data type

here is my view code

```
 <form id="myForm" action="{{route('fundwallet')}}" method="POST">
                                        @csrf
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <label for="amount"> Amount</label>
                                          <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" min="20" class="form-control">
                                      </div>
                                      <div id="response"></div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken" name="stripeToken"/>
                                          <input type="hidden" id="stripeEmail" name="stripeEmail"/>
                                        </div>
                                      </form>
                                     <button id="customButton" class="btn btn-secondary">Stripe</button>
                                     <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
                                             <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
                                             <script src="/admins/assets/vendor_components/jquery-3.3.1/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
                                      <script>
                                        var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                                          key: 'pk_test_51H0bZ0KRb4imYLNrw385vboqlKqfOTgLp85jPwivDa6qLnZDPfKuKFB0WuW8x2aky9DwRc1GYTw7NlT0PULE7nlf00m434Pv9M',
                                          image: '/square-image.png',
                                          token: function(token) {
                                              $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
                                              $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
                                              $("#myForm").submit();
                                          }
                                        });
                                      
                                        $('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
                                          var amt = $("#amount").val() *100;
                                          var amount = (2.9 / 100) * amt
                                          handler.open({
                                            name: 'VCASS',
                                            description: 'Savings for the month',
                                            amount: amount
                                          });
                                          e.preventDefault();
                                        });
                                      
                                        // Close Checkout on page navigation
                                        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
                                          handler.close();
                                        });
                                        </script>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: (1) This here `$charge = ($final_amount / 100) * 2.9;` implies that `$final_amount` is a whole number counted in cents. Therefore, when you divide it by 100 it becomes a float. .... Keep it as a whole number instead.     (2) `but when i added the stripe charges` ... Seems here you want to recoup stripe's fee onto your customer. If so you will need to round it to avoid the float result. And the same goes for the $0.30 == 30 cents, a whole number.

Comment: Furthermore, isn't it Stripe's job to get their fee on transactions? Why are you involving yourself with that part? I dont even think it works like that. Instead they are going to get their money directly from your final amount at 2.9% + $.030. It doesn't get added to the final amount. Thats why I said are you trying to "recoup" this via your customers?

Comment: yes i am trying to add it to what my customer pays, so i wont have to pay it so when my customer pays they pay the charges with it, and when stripe tries to remove the charges from me, i still have my whole number

Comment: and please how do i make the $final_amount a whole number i am newbie to coding

Comment: can you just help me restructure it the way it is supposed to be, i will really appreciate

Comment: Your existing code is not "newbie"-ish. Where'd you get it? In otherwords, if you didnt write this code, and now your question is suddenly changing from an integer error to "restructuring", thats a long winding road i dont want to go down.   .... To be fair, I already gave you insights per my 1st comment above on how to solve the invalid integer error.

Comment: lol ok you got me i am not a newbie, but i am not a pro either

Comment: Try this, `$final_charge = round($final_charge * 100);` ... Put that after you are done arriving at the final charge. Why? You need to convert back to cents (the times 100 bit) and round out the fractional part. ... Let me correct that, use `ceil()` instead of `round()` since you need an integer result.

Comment: i used round and it worked, it was rounding it off to the nearest integer

Comment: thanks man you are legend!

Comment: But represented in PHP parlance as a float, with `round()`. But if it works it works. Obviously a fractional part of 0 wont have any float precision issues.

Comment: Hey no problem. FYI due to the problem of limits (in a calculus sense) you can never fully "recoup" the Stripe fee but your method gets darn close. At least for relatively small amounts.

Comment: yea, i noticed but the client should make do with that, i don't know any other way to make it perfect